# @WithMockUser not authenticating

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-security

By annotating @WithMockUser to my test method, shouldn't the check for logged in pass and therefore redirect to '/'

```
def index() {
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect uri: '/'
    }
    else {
        redirect action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}
```

This is the controller that i am trying to test.

```
def springSecurityService = Mock( SpringSecurityService )

void setup() {
controller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
}
@WithMockUser
void "test index"() {
when:
    controller.index()
then:
    //1 * springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() >> true
    response.redirectedUrl == '/'
when:
    controller.response.reset()
    controller.index()
then:
    response.redirectedUrl == '/login/auth'
    }
```

This is my test method. If i un-comment away the line to force the check to be true, the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

`@WithMockUser` does work, here is a simple Java [example](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/1300dee4178dbf5cd63a901d5d68d5ae90aad623/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/RestWithBrowserEndpointTest.java?ts=4#L98-L108) which is part of a [sample](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/1300dee4178dbf5cd63a901d5d68d5ae90aad623/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/RestWithBrowserEndpointTest.java?ts=4#L98-L108) you can download and run yourself. Just import the entire project to your IDE

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("authenticated browser with mock user")
@WithMockUser
public void htmlRequestWithMockUser() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(
        get("/secure")
    )
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("You are authenticated")))
    ;
}
```

I'm not a big Groovy user, but my guess is that your code is not using the *real* `SpringSecurityService` object, because on the first line you have mocked it

```
def springSecurityService = Mock( SpringSecurityService )
```

To me, this looks like you're writing a test to test your mock, instead of the real object. An you have never programmed your mock to return true based on a condition. You should probably not mock the SpringSecurityService

Comment: Was playing around with the test. I def need to mock spring security service or the entire thing will not work as index() is making use of the spring security service dependancy.

Comment: If you are mocking the `SpringSecurityService` then you don't need @WithMockUser at all. because you'd mock that into the security service object itself (you mock the authentication object, not the isLoggedIn)

You use @WithMockUser when you are testing the real SpringSecurityService